# How to use setInterval inside useEffect to update the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I have never used `setInterval()` before. I am trying to make an automatic slide show. Currently, my slideshow will run once and then stop. How do I get it to continually run? I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to get this to work. Thank you!

Code specific to `setInterval()`

```
const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0)
const timeout =  React.useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const nextSlide = () => {
    setSlideIndex(current => (current === Carousel.length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1))
  }
  timeout.current  = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000)

}, [slideIndex])
```

Full Code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './Slider.css'
import BtnSlider from './BtnSlider'
import CarouselData from './CarouselData'


export default function Carousel() {

      
const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0)
const timeout =  React.useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const nextSlide = () => {
    setSlideIndex(current => (current === Carousel.length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1))
  }
  timeout.current  = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000)

}, [slideIndex])
      
    
   
    const nextSlide = () => {
        if(slideIndex !== CarouselData.length){
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex + 1)
        } 
        else if (slideIndex === CarouselData.length){
            setSlideIndex(1)
        }
    }

    const prevSlide = () => {
        if(slideIndex !== 1){
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex - 1)
        }
        else if (slideIndex === 1){
            setSlideIndex(CarouselData.length)
        }
    }

    const moveDot = index => {
        setSlideIndex(index)
    }

    

    return (
        <div className="container-slider">
            {CarouselData.map((obj, index) => {
                return (
                    <div
                    key={obj.id}
                    className={slideIndex === index + 1 ? "slide active-anim" : "slide"}
                    >
                        <img 
                        src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/Imgs/img${index + 1}.jpg`} 
                        alt="images"/>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            <BtnSlider moveSlide={nextSlide} direction={"next"} />
            <BtnSlider moveSlide={prevSlide} direction={"prev"}/>

            <div className="container-dots">
                {Array.from({length: 3}).map((item, index) => (
                    <div 
                    onClick={() => moveDot(index + 1)}
                    className={slideIndex === index + 1 ? "dot active" : "dot"}
                    ></div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CarouselData.js

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const CarouselData = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    subTitle: "Lorem"
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    subTitle: "Lorem"
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    subTitle: "Lorem"
  },
];

export default CarouselData;
```

Comment: Hi, are you able to make a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) reproducing your issue? Another option is to create a live runnable snippet with your question itself: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537)

Comment: One issue is `current === Carousel.length`, you probably meant `current === CarouselData.length`, but I don't think that is the root cuase of your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to change:

`Carousel.length` should be `CarouselData.length` because `Carousel` is the component itself.

The `useEffect` should not have `slideIndex` as a dependency as that would create a new interval every time `slideIndex` changes. And you can clear the interval when the component unmounts.

```
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const nextSlide = () => {
      setSlideIndex((current) =>
        current === CarouselData.length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1
      );
    };
    const interval = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

[image: Edit nervous-napier-cqyu5]

---

**Edit**

`slideIndex` is initially `0`. If you want to maintain `slideIndex` as zero-based, you have to make the following changes:

```
export default function Carousel() {
    const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        const nextSlide = () => {
            setSlideIndex((current) =>
                current === CarouselData.length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1
            );
        };
        const interval = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);



    const nextSlide = () => {
        setSlideIndex(index => (index === CarouselData.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1)
    }

    const prevSlide = () => {
        setSlideIndex(index => (index === 0) ? CarouselData.length - 1 : index - 1)
    }

    const moveDot = index => {
        setSlideIndex(index)
    }



    return (
        <div className="container-slider">
            {CarouselData.map((obj, index) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        key={obj.id}
                        className={slideIndex === index ? "slide active-anim" : "slide"}
                    >
                        <img
                            src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/Imgs/img${index + 1}.jpg`} // change this to just `index` if your images start with 0 (img0.jpg) 
                            alt="images" />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            <BtnSlider moveSlide={nextSlide} direction={"next"} />
            <BtnSlider moveSlide={prevSlide} direction={"prev"} />

            <div className="container-dots">
                {Array.from({ length: CarouselData.length }).map((item, index) => (
                    <div
                        onClick={() => moveDot(index)}
                        className={slideIndex === index ? "dot active" : "dot"}
                    ></div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: @Ramesh_Reddy Hi, thank you, that got the slideshow to be continuous, but I'm still having an issue. The slide show is skipping the last picture and instead showing it as a white rectangle/blank where the picture should be (the corresponding dot at the bottom is also not lit up). I originally had ```current === CarouselData.length```, but I changed it when I realized that ```current === Carousel.length``` gave me the third image (but then was causing the whole thing to stop).

Comment: @Ramesh_Reddy I added my code from CarouselData.js. Do you have any idea why this could be occurring?

Comment: @Luxe101 You should definitely use `CarouselData` and not `Carousel`. Check the updated answer

Comment: @Ramesh_Reddy Thank you so much! That last edit fixed the issue. And that makes sense!